# Group actions $S_4$ with conditions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ is a subgroup in $S_4$, which contains permutations with condition $\sigma(1) = 1$. How to find all group $G$ conjugation orbits on set $A_4$?

I tried to write this conjugation and find out what rules there we have, but I couldn't find any structure over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 6 elements in $G$ and there are 24 elements in $S_4$

For each element in $s\in S_4$ we examine $gsg^{-1}$
Elements in $G$ are still in $G$ after conjugation.
Elements not in $G$ are not in $G$ after conjugation.

If $|s| = n$ then $|gsg^{-1}|=n$.

$S_4$ has 6 elements of order 4

8 elements of order 3 (2 of which are in G)

6 single transpositions (3 of which are in G)

3 double transpositions

plus the identity element.

$O_1=\{e\}\\
O_2=\{(23),(34),(24)\}\\
O_3=\{(12),(13),(14)\}\\
O_4=\{(234),(243)\}\\
O_5=\{(123),(132),(124),(142),(134),(143)\}\\
O_6 =\{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}\\
O_7=\{(1234),(1243),(1324),(1342),(1423),(1432)\}\\
$